# Multiple Replies from Email Buttons

Tags: email, outlook

I'm having trouble with email buttons. In many cases, I receive several button responses when I should receive only one.

This always happens for some users and never happens for others.

My web site sends a transaction-type email with two buttons (essentially Yes and No) when a certain app condition occurs.  Recipients reply with one button click.

My app records the replies (button clicks) when they arrive. I save the transaction ID, the IP address of the sender and a time stamp, among other things.

I receive 5 or 6 responses from some users. Timestamps show that many of these replies are received by my app within milliseconds, 20 to 80 milliseconds, of each other. Sometimes the replies are received within 10 to 15 seconds after my site sends the original transaction email.

Some users say that they did not send the replies and they are surprised when they find that their transactions have alredy been completed.

This process worked flawlessly for 5 years, but it is progressively getting worse.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

The code is pretty simple - just an anchor tag. Outlook doesn't allow much code.

```html
<a style="display: block;color: #ffffff;font-size: 24px;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;" href="{UrlApprove}">Approve</a>
```

Comment: Some users are probably clicking the button 5-7 times due to UI lag I'm guessing. Make sure that the button becomes disabled so that they can't click it again, try a test by going into your network settings and set throttling to 3G, then try to click the button as many times as possible. Unfortunately without any code your post is pretty useless since the issue is in the code base.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I understand the need to duplicate this problem. I have never been able to do that. When I click the email button many times in succession, I get the expected response; a single receipt of my transaction is recorded on the server and a web page verifying the submission is opened in my browser.  I cannot throttle back on submission because it originates in email, not the browser.  The verification page from the server opens a new browser tab, so I can't set the throttle on that either. Can you think of any other ways I could try to duplicate the problem?

Comment: Could the problem originate externally to this process?  Could network agents, Outlook, email proxies etc. somehow intercept the button click in an attempt to detect a malicious response from my server?